# A continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ which of the following is false

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
I have been thinking of the counterexample that may work  but they are not that much easy to find I guess?  Anyone
Thnx and regards

Comment: We are given that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  The integral $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\,dt$ could be negative, in which case there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\,dt$

Comment: But is there a function I am not able to find one

Comment: Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ so $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: How could $\int f(x) dx$ be negative if $f(x) \ge 0$?  Also $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} 2f(\frac {x-1}2) dx$ and $f(\frac{x-1}/2)$ is also continuous non neg.  So if that is the argument against c, then it is also an argument against d.

Comment: @MyGlasses An even easier examle:  Let $f(x) = k \ne 0$.  Then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = (b-a)k = k = f(c) \iff b = a+ 1$.

Comment: @fleablood Is this one satisfies No.(D).?

Comment: Yours and mine both fail c) and satisfy d).  I'm just pointing out an easier counter example to c).   All continuous functions satisfy d) (because... d is true....)  many will and many will not satisfy c).  To come up with an argument for d) I saw there'll always be an x so that f(x) = 1/b $\int_{a}^{a+b} f(x) dx$ and I wanted a counter example so that  $\int_{a}^{a+b} f(x) dx$ never equals any $f(x)$.  Constant functions came immediately to mind.

Comment: Man, I'd like to get into the mindset of these weirdo downvoters.  This is good question.  And the OP is not just asking for answers   There's nothing wrong with a poster being totally lost, as long as the acknowledge where they are getting lost.

Comment: @Fleablood nice answer it's very useful I wish I could have thought that way......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intermediate and mean value theorems say that: if we let $\min f(x)$ be the minimum value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ and let $\max f(x)$ be the maximum value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ then $(b-a)*\min f(x) \le \int_{a}^b f(x) dx \le (b-a)\max f(x)$ or $\min f(x) \le \frac{\int_{a}^b f(x) dx}{b-a}\le \max f(x)$ and as $f$ is continuous we therefore know there is a $c: a \le c \le b$ so that $f(c) = \frac{\int_{a}^b f(x) dx}{b-a}$.

If  $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ we know there is a $c: 0 \le c \le 1$ so that $f(c) = \int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$.  That gives us $d$.

If $a = -1 $ and $b = 1$ we know there is a $c: -1 \le c \le 2$ so that $f(c) = \frac 12 \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$.  That does not give us $c$.

But lack of a proof isn't proof of a lack.  we have a hint.  There will always be a value that is the value that is *half* the value of an integer two units long (or $\frac 1b$ the integer $b$ long).

Let $f(x) = k > 0$ a constant function.  Then $\int_{a}^b f(x) dx = (b-a) k$.   This will never equal any $f(x)$  unless $b = a+1$.

So $c$ is not true.

====

And, as you probably figured $\frac {f(0) + f(1)}2$ is the arithmetic average value of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ so $\min(f(0), f(1)) \le \frac {f(0) + f(1)}2 \le \max (f(0), f(1))$.

Less obvious $\sqrt{f(-1)f(1)}$ is the geometric average and, assuming both $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ are non negative then $\min(f(0), f(1)) \le \sqrt{f(-1)f(1)} \le \max (f(0), f(1))$

====

Also note the actual choices of $0, 1, -1$ where irrelevant except in the case of $c$ and $d$ where we only need to note in $c$ that $1-0 = 1$ and in $d$ that $1-(-1) \ne 1$.