# which one of the following is NOT TRUE?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm unable to find a continuous function for option (C). Please explain option (C) with counterexample And Option (C) implies option (D) by the integral property. I know that the option (B) is NOT TRUE but I want explanation for option (C) only

[image]

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: can i take f(x) = 0 then only the codition is satisfied for option (C) and (D) ?

Comment: Take $f(x) = 1$?

Comment: I don't see how B could be false. Clearly, $\sqrt{f(-1)f(1)}$ lies between $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$, and since $f$ is continuous...

Comment: If I take f(x) = 1 then  value of RHS =2 which is not equal to LHS

Comment: Since √f(−1)f(1) can be imaginary if f(-1) < 0 and f(1) > 0

Comment: $f(-1)$ can't be negative. The question states that $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, \infty)$. (B) is true.

Comment: A duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168756/a-continuous-function-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-which-of-the-following

Answer (score 1):

For $(C)$

$\displaystyle \underset{[-1,1]}\inf f\int_{-1}^{1}dt\le\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt\le \underset{[-1,1]}\sup f\int_{-1}^{1}dt\iff 2\underset{[-1,1]}\inf f\le\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt\le 2\underset{[-1,1]}\sup f$

so $f: x\to \cos^2(x)$ is counterexample

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(t)dt =\int_{0}^{1}1+\cos(2t)dt=\bigg[t+\dfrac{\sin(2t)}{2}\bigg]^1_0=1+\dfrac{\sin2 }{2}>1\ge f(x)\ge0,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$